# How to make a formula of ppf in Java

Tags: java, android, mathematical-expressions

I would like to know to define the formula of ppf (public provident fund )in java code.

I have tried

```
p*(Math.pow(1+i/100,t));
```

but I am getting it wrong

Pff formula is:

```
F = P[{(1+i)n-1}/i]
```

where,

- ‘F’ stands for the maturity amount of the PPF
- ‘P’ stands for the annual instalments paid
- ‘n’ stands for the number of years or tenure of the PPF
- ‘i’ stands for the rate of interest.

The formula works like duration - 3 years and interest -7.1%

1      0            1,00,000    7,100.04        1,07,100

2     1,07,100     1,00,000     14,704.08       2,21,804

3    2,21,804       1,00,000    22,848.12       3,44,652

Comment: PLease make a [MRE] and provide the error message

Comment: What is `t` and `p`? Is `(1+i)n-1` suppose to be `(1+i)` to the power of `n-1`? What are you getting from your code? What did you expect it to be?

Comment: T refer to time and p is refer to the principal amount. I am getting a correct and if I put a small number but when I pass big number so I am getting a wrong answer